# AND operator across multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me to modify following SQL query.

```
select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose IN(1,2);
```

In this query I'm using IN operator with purpose. Which gives me all pids who have purpose = 1 OR purpose 2. But, I want to select all pids who've purpose =1 AND purpose 2,

```
PID         A   P   S       D 
612747617   0   1   0       27300 
612747617   1   2   28740   29280 
612747617   2   1   59700   60 
612747617   3   4   61200   120 
612747617   4   1   62700   37300 
612747631   0   1   0       36000 
612747631   1   4   36600   2100 
612747631   2   4   43200   56800
```

Sample data in vt_activities_2009_1 table looks like above.

Where A for anum, P for purpose etc.

I can't simply use where purpose = 1 and purpose = 2.

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please put your query in code blocks.

Comment: `But, I want to select all pids who've purpose =1 AND purpose 2`, how can a field hold multiple values at the same time, in other words, how could `purpose` be `1` and `2` at the same time ?

Comment: Thanks Philip Devine

Comment: @habib look at the pids, many to one ratio.

Comment: Habib, if yous see my table carefully. Each PIDs have multiple puproses. Each row is for a single purpose. across the rows. So, I want to select "PIDs who've purpose =1 AND purpose = 2". So in above example I my query should only return 612747617 as answer. Since only this PID has purpose = 1 and purpose = 2.

Comment: @user2632316, oh yes, missed that.

Comment: @user2632316 my solution solves the question, if it didn't answer your question that's fine. But if it helped provide you with the solution then accepting it would be a common courtesy. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    select pid 
      from your_table
     where purpose=1
  intersect
    select pid 
      from your_table
     where purpose=2;
```

I think that ought to do it.

Actually just thought of this which will do it in one pass through the table:

```
select pid
  from (
        select pid
          from my table
         where purpose in(1,2)
       )
group by pid
having count(*) = 2;
```

That should be a single pass through the table.

Comment: ...not if there can be multiple rows for the same pid and same purpose though

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FIPS, count(pid) from
(SELECT distinct sa.* 
from(
    SELECT p.pid, concat(lpad(h.state, 2, '0'), lpad(h.county,3,'0')) FIPS 
    FROM PERSON_2009_1 p,HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 h
    WHERE p.schg = 4
    AND p.agep BETWEEN 10 AND 25
    and p.hid = h.hid) sa
where sa.pid in (select pid from activities_2009_1 x where exists(select 1 from activities_2009_1 y where x.pid = y.pid and purpose =1) 
and exists(select 1 from activities_2009_1 y where x.pid = y.pid and purpose =2)
)group by FIPS order by FIPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FIPS, count(pid) from(SELECT distinct sa.* from(SELECT p.pid, concat(lpad(h.state, 2, '0'), lpad(h.county,3,'0')) FIPS
                       FROM PERSON_2009_1 p,HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 h
                             WHERE p.schg = 4 AND p.agep BETWEEN 10 AND 25 and p.hid = h.hid)
                             sa  where sa.pid in ((select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 1) as a inner join (select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 2) as b on (a.pid = b.pid))
                             )group by FIPS order by FIPS;
```

I am using an inner join (an intersect). Not the most efficient, but should work.

Below is my first thoughts just using an AND:

```
SELECT FIPS, count(pid) from(SELECT distinct sa.* from(SELECT p.pid, concat(lpad(h.state, 2, '0'), lpad(h.county,3,'0')) FIPS
                   FROM PERSON_2009_1 p,HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 h
                         WHERE p.schg = 4 AND p.agep BETWEEN 10 AND 25 and p.hid = h.hid)
                         sa  where sa.pid in ((select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 1) ANDas sa.pida ininner join (select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 2) as b on (a.pid = b.pid))
                         )group by FIPS order by FIPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want this:

```
SELECT FIPS, count(pid) from
( SELECT distinct sa.* from
  (SELECT p.pid, concat(lpad(h.state, 2, '0'), lpad(h.county,3,'0')) FIPS
     FROM PERSON_2009_1 p,HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 h
    WHERE p.schg = 4
      AND p.agep BETWEEN 10 AND 25 
      and p.hid = h.hid
  ) sa
  where sa.pid in (select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 1)
    AND sa.pid in (select pid from activities_2009_1 where purpose = 2)
)
group by FIPS order by FIPS;
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT FIPS, count(pid) from
( SELECT distinct sa.* from
  (SELECT p.pid, concat(lpad(h.state, 2, '0'), lpad(h.county,3,'0')) FIPS
     FROM PERSON_2009_1 p,HOUSEHOLD_2009_1 h
    WHERE p.schg = 4
      AND p.agep BETWEEN 10 AND 25 
      and p.hid = h.hid
  ) sa
  where 2 =  (select count(distinct a.purpose)
                from activities_2009_1 a 
               where a.pid = sa.pid
                 and a.purpose in (1,2))
)
group by FIPS order by FIPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick for you...

```
SELECT PID
     , A
     , P
     , S
     , D
  FROM ACTIVITIES_2009_1
 WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID
                 FROM (  SELECT PID, COUNT (*)
                           FROM ACTIVITIES_2009_1
                          WHERE P = 1
                             OR P = 2
                       GROUP BY PID
                         HAVING COUNT (*) > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a job to tables `a` and `b`. `a` will verify existence of purpose=1, and `b` will verify existence of purpose=2. If either purpose is missing, the row will be removed by the `inner join`.

```
select a.pid 
from activities_2009_1 a
  inner join activities_2009_1 b    
       on a.pid=b.pid
where a.purpose=1 and b.purpose=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving you the answer to your immediate problem, how about we talk about what `select` means.

In its simple form `select <columns> from <table> where <conditions>` is almost self explaining. What gets selected (returned) are rows in the table for which the conditions are true. In order to implement the condition you want ("there is a p=1 and p=2 for the same pid") you'll first have to make sure the two p columns are in the same row. Let's repeat that. In order to implement the condition you want ("there is a p=1 and p=2 for the same pid") you'll first have to make sure the two p columns are in the same row.

That's what a join can do for you: align the rows in two tables to create a new one with values from both. In this case a join (align) on the pid, and a check on left.p=1 and right.p=2 achieves that. I'm sure there's an example of that in one of the other answers (l and r refer to the two tabels that get joined ("left" and "right"), in this case the same table twice.

The examples that use `count()=2` are pretty clever and (probably) efficient but rely on the assumption (or constraint) that every pid+p combination is unique.

As for efficiency of your (join) queries, I suggest you start caring about that after you've got the sql syntax down (and also indexes, normalized/denormalized db designs, and constraints). The time gained by an 'efficient running' query may not outweigh the time lost in developer inefficiency/due to code unclarity. Hardware scales way easier than humanware.